# migrate js to tsx in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I try to migrate my js file to tsx.

when page load a page, alldata will set from my api, so before the api set, alldata just empty array

```js
import classes from "./vertification.module.scss";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCheck } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { getAllVertification } from "../../helpers/database";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Vertification() {
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);
  const [allData, setAlldata] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = async () => {
      const data = await getAllVertification();
      if (!data.status) {
      } else {
        setAlldata(data.data);
      }
    };

    data();
  }, [update]);
  return (
    <div className={classes.vertification}>
      <div className={classes.tab}>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {allData.map((data, key) => {
              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{data.identityType.toUpperCase()}</td>
                  <td>{data.identityNumber}</td>
                  <td>{data.nationality}</td>
                  <td>{data.firstName}</td>
                  <td>{data.secondName}</td>
                  <td>
                    {data.gender.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data.gender.slice(1)}
                  </td>
                  <td>{data.birthDate}</td>
                  <td>{data.bornCountry}</td>
                  <td>{data.profession}</td>
                  <td>{data.province}</td>
                  <td>{data.city}</td>
                  <td>{data.address}</td>
                  <td>{data.postCode}</td>
                  <td>img</td>
                  <td>
                    <button>
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

actually my code still working normal when run, but got an warning like this
[image]

can someone explain to me and help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define the fetched data type at the service method

```
const getAllVertification= async(url:string,config?:AxiosRequestConfig):Promise<DataType[]>=>{
  const {data,status} = axios.get<DataType[]>(url,config);
  return data // Note then you do not need read it like, data.data, just data
// if you need status in component you can return status too. Or just a comparison like if(data.length>0) in component
}
```

Where DataType can be

```
interface DataType { identityType:string, identityNumber:number,.... }
```

Then define the type for state

```
const [allData, setAlldata] = useState<DataType[]>([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add {**allData &&** allData.map((data, key)} for validate the empty array or not. Moreover, you should have define data type in when initials the variable.

Comment: Since it is an array, I think this shouldn't be a problem. [`Proof`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-u1ahj3)

Answer (score 1):

You first have to create the type of `data.data` in your `useEffect` via an interface. I think it is a `User`. Then your code like below:

```
const [allData, setAlldata] = useState<User[]>([]);
```

When you complete these steps, you should access each property of the data and errors should be gone.

**Edit**: You can define a type with `interface`. From what I deduce, I created one.

```
interface User {
  identityType: string,
  identityNumber: number,
  nationality: string,
  firstName: string,
  secondName: string,
  gender: string,
  birthDate: Date,
  bornCountry: string,
  profession: string,
  province: string,
  city: string,
  address: string,
  postCode: number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your allData was assigned to an empty array here

```
const [allData, setAlldata] = useState([]);
```

and thus has the type never[]
You can temporarily fix the error using

```
const [allData, setAlldata] = useState<any>([]);
```

until you define a type for the entries.
If you do already have a type ( or you end up defining one) simply replace `any` with it
like so (in case your type would be named user , which looks likely with the data you're having ) :

```
const [allData, setAlldata] = useState<User>([]);
```

The type definition would look something like this :

```
interface User {
  nationality: string;
  firstName: string;
  province?: string;
}
```

use `?` to specify that a certain field is optional, you can read more on interfaces in the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)